# When I click on menu button (onlick) it opens and then close instantly

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

When I click on my element which uses onlick event it opens as it should but then instantly closes. At first I had my script in other file, I used script src method. Then I tried to move the script to the bottom of body section, nothing. Tried to move the script at the start of body section still nothing. I even checked on W3Schools and their example is same as mine!

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    
<header>
    <h1>Joy Division</h1>
    <nav class="nav">
    <a href="" ><img src="../img/menu.png" id="menu_button" onclick="menuOpen()"></a>
    <div id="navbar_active">
        <a href="" ><img src="../img/back.jpg" id="menu_back" onclick="menuClose()"></a>
        <li><a href="discography.html">Discography</a></li>
        <li><a href="members.html">Band Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="neworder.html">New Order</a></li>
    </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<script>function menuOpen() {
    document.getElementById("menu_button").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("navbar_active").style.display = "block";
     
 }
 
 function menuClose() {
     document.getElementById("navbar_active").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("menu_button").style.display = "block";
 }
 </script>

</body>
```

My CSS code:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../img/background1.jpg') ;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

body {
    color: white;
}

header {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: Perpetua Titling MT;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;

}

#menu_button{
    display: block ;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}

nav a img:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}


#navbar_active {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -1.75em;
    margin-top: -2.8em;
    width: 420px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: inherit;
    mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(170deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    opacity: 0.9;
}


#navbar_active img {
    margin-top: 2.8em;
    margin-left: 20em;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

#navbar_active li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 4em;
    padding-top: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

#navbar_active li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Perpetua Titling MT;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
}

#navbar_active li a:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Than why do you use `href=""` ? Don't be afraid to remove `href=""` or even better use `<button type="button">` if *button* is what you want.

Comment: I didn't know it will affect the results like this. I deleted anchor tags and it works now. Thank you very much! I'm angry for myself that I didn't tried to do something with this anchor tags before....

Comment: You're very welcome. Happy coding BTW